# GridFS Node.JS Native Driver - How to get ignore ContentType?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, content-type, gridfs

I'm interacting with `MongoDB` with several drivers including `PyMongo` and `Node.js Native MongoDB driver`.
What I noticed is that when I do `fs.put` for `GridFS` storage from `PyMongo` it only sets few fields including `UploadDate`, but when I do `fs.put` for `GridFS` storage from `Node.JS` it also inserts additional fields to storage that I don't need including `ContentType`.

That may be good practice, but I dont want this field, how do I configure MongoDB insert to ignore insertion of this field when adding file to `GridFS` from `Node.JS`? According to [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/grid.html#put) you can either set it or it will use default `ContentType` (content_type).

How to not insert this field it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems like there's no support for this feature. So I just commented stuff for fields contentType and aliases in [MongoDB Driver library for Node.JS](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/gridfs/grid_store.js). Its bad practice, but unfortunately there's no another option for that right now.